# Ruby on Rails: replace data with images in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've looked around but haven't found anything that answers this exact question.

I have a data field in my view that comes in from an external API and without manipulation, it will display like this:

```
{A} {B} {X} {G}
```

How can I replace the text string so that every letter displays a small icon instead? I tried converting it in a view helper but then it just displays the html without linking to the image like this:

```
<img src="A.svg"> <img src="B.svg"> etc.
```

How can I get erb to parse the html tags and link to the image?

Answer (score 1):

Mark your strings safe using `html_safe` method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe

Only do this if you are sure that these strings can't contain any unsafe data like raw user input.

**edit:** Actually it's better to use `image_tag` method if possible:

```
image_tag("#{letter}.svg")
```